# PHP FB-API blocking

Tags: php, facebook

I am using FB/php-sdk library from github and getting this message after long simulation. Does anyone know how to stop it? Thank you in advance.

> "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: 368: Youâ€™re Temporarily
>   Blocked: It looks like you were going too fast and misusing this
>   feature, so youâ€™ve been blocked from it for up to two days. Learn
>   more about blocks in the Body of an error/warning message. Title is:
>   Youâ€™re Temporarily Blocked. thrown in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\vendor\facebook\php-sdk\src\base_facebook.php on
>   line 1254"

Comment: What is your script doing?

Comment: There is nothing the users of [so] can do to help you here. The error message contains all the information you'll be able to get (even from Facebook). It seems that your application is simply making too many calls to the API and Facebook has observed this behavior to be harmful
 - so they blocked you.